# Using RCurl with ftp server with embedded nulls

Tags: r, ftp, rcurl

I've been working on this issue for a few days now and even after contacting the site administrators, I've had no luck in solving it.

I would like to automate the download of a specific file from an ftp server without using any software besides R.

```
userpwd = "MyUserName:MyPassword" 
url <- "ftp://arthurhou.pps.eosdis.nasa.gov/gpmdata/2014/04/01/imerg/3B-HHR.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S150000-E152959.0900.V03D.HDF5"
dat <- try(getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd,verbose=TRUE,ftp.use.epsv = FALSE))
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string:      '‰HDF\r\n\032\n\0\0\0\0\0\b\b\0\004\0\020\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÚá'\0\0\0\0\0ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0OHDR\002,fÉ¿TbÉ¿TfÉ¿TbÉ¿Tà\002"\0\0\0\0\0\003\001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ\n\002\0\001\0\0\0\0\006\027\0\0\0\0\001\004\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\004Grid[\001\0\0\0\0\0\0\025\034\0\004\0\0\0\003\002\0ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ\020\020\0\0\0\0\036`&\0\0\0\0\0{\003\0\0\0\0\0\0\0U\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\024î*aOHDR\002,fÉ¿TbÉ¿TfÉ¿TbÉ¿Tà\002"\0\0\0\0\0\003\v\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Ã\025\0\0\0\0\0\0U\026\0\0\0\0\0\0{\026\0\0\0\0\0\0\n\002\0\001\0\0\0\0\025\034\0\004\0\0\0\003\001\0ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ\020\020\0\0\0\0™c&\0\0\0\0\0\034\001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0r\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
```

I've tried removing the nulls from the initial link, i.e. `url <- "ftp://arthurhou.pps.eosdis.nasa.gov%2Fgpmdata%2F2014%2F04%2F01%2Fimerg%2F3B-HHR.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S213000-E215959.1290.V03D.HDF5"` yet this returns the same error as before.

If anyone would like to try this for themselves, you can register an email at: http://pmm.nasa.gov/data-access/downloads/gpm, and then use the email as the username and password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
library(httr)

url <- "ftp://arthurhou.pps.eosdis.nasa.gov/gpmdata/2014/04/01/imerg/3B-HHR.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S150000-E152959.0900.V03D.HDF5"

output_file <- "3B-HHR.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S150000-E152959.0900.V03D.HDF5"

my_email <- "someone@example.com"

GET(url, authenticate(my_email, my_email), 
    write_disk(output_file))
```